# Trouble With Creating A Global Hotkey To Write Out The Contents Of A Text File Without Unfocusing From Active Window

Tags: python, focus, hook, shortcut, hotkeys

I created a very simple Python script that should read the contents of a text file and then simulate them as keypresses.

```py
import keyboard

File_object = open("commandText.txt", "r")

keyboard.write(File_object.read())

File_object.close()
```

I want to have it do so for another application without stealing the focus away from that application. I tried using shortcut keys to trigger a shortcut file to run its associated batch file that runs `python3 RunCommand.py` which is the code shown above. Every time I use the shortcut keys, the application I am focused on becomes unfocused, even when I specified for the shortcut to run minimized.

I tried using nircmd and hide the batch script, but the issue seems to be with opening the shortcut file, as it automatically becomes focused instead of the application I want to use it on every time I use the hotkey. The Python code has been tested and works fine so that if I click on notepad in time, my text is written out as expected. That being said, the program I'm trying to write to is not text-editing software and I do not have access to the program's API, therefore I'm using Python.

In short, I'm looking to possibly hook a global key combination that can be detected when the cmd terminal is not in focus, and then have it trigger the pre-written text from the txt file to be simulated with keypresses without unfocusing from the window I'm working on. Issues I've had with waiting for hotkeys are high-cpu usage and reduced performance on other software, so I am looking for as lightweight a solution as possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Additional info:
I tried running NirCmd, VBS scripts, and AutoHotKey (which I frankly do not know enough about to use exclusively). I can't get the main window to remain focused without simulating a mouse click, which could have chaotic results if my window doesn't extend to where the mouse is located.

(OS Windows 10, version of Python installed: Python 3.10)

Comment: you probably want to explore modules like: `PyAutoGUI` and `PyWinAuto`....  it will also depend on the operating system, so please specify this.

Comment: However, if you are just wanting to write text to a file, then this would be the wrong approach...  this would be better `with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:`...

Comment: @D.L Thank you very much for the quick reply. I know of and have used PyAutoGUI and PyWinAuto, but I don't quite know how to apply them in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the correct about opening up the file as an object (I meant to add this in my comment, I just forgot to hold down shift before hitting enter).
Is there a way to hook the key combination directly in Python without slowing down or lagging the system?

Comment: the best way by far is to write directly to text file without trying to control other apps to achieve the same. But i (or others) didn't show the full answer because the question did not ask for this and users need to answer the question :-)

Comment: D.L I just realized what you meant. No I don't want it to write text to a file, but rather read the text I had written to a file and then simulate keypresses that will type everything in the file. In this way, I hope to create a sort of macro using only Python.
Sorry that I failed to clarify this properly in my main post.

Comment: it might be better to amend the question like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then myself or other users will be able to help you effectively.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful information, I will promptly fix my question.